# ASP.NET Core Runtime Compilation fails with "Cannot find compilation library location for package" for dynamically loaded Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the following code to dynamically load a Razor Class Library into my `ASP.NET Core 3.0` app:

```
var pluginAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName);
var partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(pluginAssembly);
foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(pluginAssembly))
    MvcBuilder.PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(part);

var relatedAssemblies = RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(pluginAssembly, throwOnError: true);
foreach (var assembly in relatedAssemblies)
{
    partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(assembly);
    foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(assembly))
        MvcBuilder.PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
}
```

This works fine and controllers and views are initially working. But if I also add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package and the following to the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "..\\AppPlugin")));
    });
```

I get the following exception as soon as I edit a `*.cshtml`-file:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location
>   for package 'AppPlugin'
>
> - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver
>     resolver, List assemblies)
> - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPartExtensions+<>c.b__0_0(CompilationLibrary
>     library)
> - System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator.MoveNext()
> - System.Collections.Generic.List.InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable collection)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetReferencePaths()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()

**Is there something else I need to load to get this to work?**
If I omit the plugin-path from the `FileProviders` runtime-compilation works for "non-plugin-views".

Comment: Have you tried something like this:`services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(options => options.FileProviders.Add(
        new PhysicalFileProvider(appDirectory)));`?

Comment: @Rena Thanks for the input, but that did not help :-(

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working by using the following project settings for the razor class library.  The key piece was to set PreserveCompilationContext to false.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In Addition to this, you'll have to add a reference to your main plugin assembly and any additional assemblies used in your views.

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "..\\AppPlugin")));
    opts.AdditionalReferencePaths.Add(pluginAssembly.Location);
});
```

Comment: This worked as well for me; although I am not quite sure about why this worked. Can you help me understand it better?

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**
In .net6 when you use both:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

you have the error message:

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Build'`

**Solution**
Uninstall `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package and you'll be able to use razor runtime compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still missing references after defining razor runtime compilation as described in other answers and missing types are located in namespaces referenced as `global using` e.g. `global using MyNamespace.Extensions;` try to explicitly add your namespaces to `_ViewImports.cshtml` or directly into view with `@using MyNamespace.Extensions`