# ASP.NET Core Runtime Compilation fails with “Cannot find compilation library location for package” for dynamically loaded Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, plugins, .net-5

This is a follow-up question to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797751/asp-net-core-runtime-compilation-fails-with-cannot-find-compilation-library-loc), as with .NET 5.0 I took another go at that project and it behaves differently and I can't get it to work anymore.

I use the following code to dynamically load a Razor Class Library into my `.NET 5.0` `ASP.NET Core` app:

```
var pluginAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName);
var partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(pluginAssembly);
foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(pluginAssembly))
    MvcBuilder.PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(part);

var relatedAssemblies = RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(pluginAssembly, throwOnError: true);
foreach (var assembly in relatedAssemblies)
{
    partFactory = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(assembly);
    foreach (var part in partFactory.GetApplicationParts(assembly))
        MvcBuilder.PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
}
```

This works fine and controllers and views are initially working. But if I also add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package and the following to the `Startup.cs`

```
var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

I get the following exception as soon as I change ANY view:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location
> for package 'AppPlugin'
>
> - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List assemblies)
> - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPartExtensions+<>c.b__0_0(CompilationLibrary library)
> - System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
> - System.Collections.Generic.List.InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable collection)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetReferencePaths()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
> - System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func valueFactory)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
> - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)

This is different than before, because now it fails as soon as the plugin is loaded, no matter if there is a `FileProvider` for the plugin's views path registered or not and the solution from the old question does not work anymore.

**Does anybody know how I can get that to work?**

Comment: were you able to solve it , i am having the same issue weird thing is one of my plugins working perfectly fine while others dont

Comment: @Alok It is working on my side again, but I can't say what exactly made it work again, but I'm also not actively working on this project at the moment, so maybe problems arise again. I'm waiting for .NET 6 to further work on this, because this is changing there (no Views-Assembly anymore)...

Comment: hi @Christoph Fink , i traced my issue to 2 things... 1. the projects using common views from RCL have this error, 2. i have DB FileProviders for dynamic views.. now here both are hit asi put some logger code to see if it was even finding the view... but it seems the razor engine just doesnt stop after that and pipeline continues for searching god knows which locations, i can wait for net 6 this is killing me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797751/asp-net-core-runtime-compilation-fails-with-cannot-find-compilation-library-loc

Issue In .net6 when you use both:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
you have the error message:

Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Build'`

Solution Uninstall Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package and you'll be able to use razor runtime compile.